# Netbeans: how to upload file into different folder?

Tags: netbeans, ftp, directory, sftp, file-upload

I would like to upload a files in Netbeans, for example from: `C:/my_folder` in my computer into `/home/public_html` folder on the server. I've specified initial path as `/home` and upload directory as `/public_html`, and in the properties my path looks like this: `sftp://host.name.com/home/public_html`.

But when I upload files I find them in the `/home/public_html/my_folder` ... how to fix it? Because I've tried all options in the properties but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new project and set your project folder to `C:/my_folder`. Set your upload path to `/home/public_html` as you have.

Now, if you have a file `C:/my_folder/x.html` it will be uploaded to `/home/public_html/x.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step instructions to upload files from Netbeans.

http://www.gridsandguides.com/blog/how-to-use-net-beans-to-edit-file-on-server

Comment: Please don't post link only answers as links may break.